# I'm trying to convert pixel data to an OpenCV Mat object

Tags: c++, opencv

I have raw pixel data that I want to output via the opencv cvShowImage() function.

I have the following code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

// pdata is the raw pixel data as 3 uchars per pixel
static char bitmap[640*480*3];
memcpy(bitmap,pdata,640*480*3);
cv::Mat mat(480,640,CV_8UC3,bitmap);

std::cout << mat.flags << ", "
          << mat.dims  << ", "
          << mat.rows  << ", "
          << mat.cols  << std::endl;

cvShowImage("result",&mat);
```

Which outputs:

```
1124024336, 2, 480, 640
```

to the console, but fails to output the image with cvShowImage(). Instead throwing an exception with the message:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat
```

I suspect the problem is in the way I create the mat object, but I am having a very hard time finding any more specific information on how I am supposed to do that.

I don't think CV_8UC3 is enough of a description for it to render the array of data. Doesn't it have to know whether the data is RGB or YUY2, etc.? How do I set that?

Comment: Try `cv::imshow("result", mat)` instead of mixing the old C and new C++ APIs. I expect casting a `Mat` to a `CvArr*` is the problem.

Comment: @Roger, after at first misreading your comment, I have at last found that this solution fixes my problem, if you make this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cv::imshow("result", mat)` instead of mixing the old C and new C++ APIs. I expect casting a `Mat` to a `CvArr*` is the source of the problem.

So, something like this:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

// pdata is the raw pixel data as 3 uchars per pixel
static char bitmap[640*480*3];
memcpy(bitmap,pdata,640*480*3);
cv::Mat mat(480,640,CV_8UC3,bitmap);

std::cout << mat.flags << ", "
          << mat.dims  << ", "
          << mat.rows  << ", "
          << mat.cols  << std::endl;

cv::imshow("result", mat);
```

Comment: and I believe the imshow() function always expects the mat object to be either grey (when in 8UC1) or bgr (when in 8UC3).